# Blackberry Platform

Tags: blackberry, platform

Currently i am working on Blackberry JDE 4.3 and i want to know that is there any other platform for Blacberry onwhich we can easily make applications with short time. Such as in Blacberrry JDE, to handle graphics you have to include so many api's and there exists many complexities in the JDE platform.

Comment: Blackberry apps are written in java so the apis are there to help you write less code.  Not sure I understand your question fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try J2ME API to develop the blackberry application, but its not right platform  to over all feature implemented in Blackberry RIM.

Blackberry JDE 5.0 plays vital role in UI and Graphics API,

Try it!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried working with blackberry eclipse plugin
i feel it better than the jde